# Having and issue registering my service worker using react typescript lcoalhost?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, progressive-web-apps

I have the following regitrastion chain

```js
export function register() {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register("./service-worker.ts")
    .then(() => console.log("Passed"))
    .catch((err) => alert("Reg Error"));
}
```

my current file structure looks like this
[image]

and I am getting the following error

**The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').**